# Temporaries optimization in chaining operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have an `Array` class **which is expensive to construct a new instance**. I defined `operator+` for it to be able to chain up like this.

```cpp
class Array
{
public:
    //...
    Array& operator+=(Array const&);
    Array operator+(Array const&);
};

Array a, b, c, d;
Array e = a + b + c + d; //a+b->Temp, Temp+c->Temp2, Temp2+d->e, BAD!
```

I want it to be able to use `operator+=` which saves the cost of constructing a new instance, instead of using `operator+` which will construct a new instance. I tried using reference qualifier like this:

```cpp
Array operator+(Array const&) &;
Array& operator+(Array const&) &&; //call += internally
```

But after `Temp+c->Temp`, `Temp+d` will call `operator+() &` which still create new instance.

EDIT: I tried

```cpp
Array&& operator+(Array const&) &&
{
    //...
    return std::move(*this);
}
```

Which seems to work, but will it dangle? Because `Array e = a + b + c + d;` will call move constructor to move the final temporary into `e` and I can do some tricks in the move constructor to prevent the resource being freed when the temporary is destoried after the expression, if I am correct.

Comment: `Array::operator+` could return a different class `Array_Temp`. `Array_Temp` casts back to array, but before that we add another `Array` to `Array_Temp`. This way you would only create a new `Array`(`_Temp`) at the first addition. I think I saw something a long this line at [fluentcpp](https://www.fluentcpp.com), but couldn't find the correct post yet.

Comment: Look up expression templates, it's not a perfect solution but it works.